# My blogspot main page shows only 3 post

Tags: blogspot

I want to show 12 posts on each page but this always show 3 posts. I have change the number of post on main page in Blog Post Widget but this isn't working, my blog is always show 3 post in the main page, this is my blog: http://onepiece-data.blogspot.com/.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: What did you do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 6):

Apparently on some 3rd party blog templates you have to put a jump break after the first photo in each blogpost in order for them to show correctly on the homepage.

like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz6PT.png

this page have explained about what are jump breaks 
https://blogger.googleblog.com/2009/09/you-might-as-well-jump.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change that from the default settings.

> Go to Blogger >> Your blog >> Layout >> Look for 'Blog Posts' and
>   click on 'edit'

[image]

Change it to any number you want.

Comment: I have noticed that on blogger that date of the post also affects this setting. Even when the setting is set to seven, if there are no seven posts within the last month or so, blogger only shows the posts within the date range. This is where the Older Post filter comes into play.