# Blogger / Blogspot: How to show list of all posts instead of "Older Posts" link?

Tags: blogs, blogger, blogspot

I have a blog ([Curiosity Cup](http://www.curiositycup.in/))
hosted on blogspot.com.

1. However, on 1 page it shows only 2-3 posts and user has to click on "older posts" link to view previous posts. I tried changing number of posts per page in the settings->formatting option but still no success. Is there a way to make this work?

I have already tried what is described in this answer: [My blogspot main page shows only 3 post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326188/my-blogspot-main-page-shows-only-3-post?rq=1)
but it's not working in my case.

2. I tried editing the blog archive widget to show a list of post titles instead of date hierarchy. I tried this link: [Show post titles instead of date hierarchy](http://www.myoutsourcedbrain.com/2009/11/blogger-archive-pages-with-only-post.html) but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to the first part of my question:
First thing is to use the page breaks so that your post gets shortened for the home page. Next things (and I was doing this mistake) is to NOT include images before the page break. Apparently I was including large images before page break and although they may or may not appear in shortened view but they were blocking the space that should have been used by other posts.

Answer to second part of my question can be found here:

[stackoverflow.com/a/26335753/2458858](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26335753/2458858)